# file_get_contents() not working with $_REQUEST variables

Tags: php, request, file-get-contents

I have a php script that takes a variable from a form using $_REQUEST (`$query = $_REQUEST['query'];`) and takes contents from `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$query` (and credits wikipedia for results).

The problem is that `file_get_contents();` for the wikipedia page only worked when i set `$query = "custom string, not requested one";`, but when I try a `$_REQUEST`ed string, it returns an empty string.

Can anyone find a solution for this?

Thanks, Domi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are getting value in your `$query` variable and then make your requested url as

```
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
$url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/".$query;
```

then use file_get_contents() as

```
$result=file_get_contents($url);
```